# Use only the rules of inference to derive a logic statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Question: Given the two propositions: P1: (a $\lor$ b) $\land$ (c $\lor$ d). P2: $\neg$b $\land$ $\neg$ c. Use only the rules of inferences to derive ($\neg$a $\lor$ d) $\land$ ($\neg$d $\lor$ a).

I can only get to the following steps by using rules of inferences:

(1) $\neg b \land \neg c$ => $\neg b \space and \space \neg c$

(2) (a $\lor$ b) $\land$ (c $\lor$ d) => (a $\lor$ b) and (c $\lor$ d)

(3) (a $\lor$ b) $\equiv \neg a$ -> b and (c $\lor$ d) $\equiv$ $\neg c$ -> d

(4) Because $\neg a$ -> b and $\neg b$, therefore, a

(5) Because $\neg c$ -> d and $\neg c$, therefore, d

(6) Because a, d, therefore, $a \land d$

(7) $a \land d \equiv \neg(d \rightarrow \neg a) \equiv \neg (\neg a \lor \neg d)$

These are the farest steps I have gone to derive the final statement by using rules of inferences only.

Comment: What are your inference rules ? See e.g. [List of rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I didn't list them, but generally they are those simple inference rules.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) you are allowed to use...

For example, with [Simplification (or Conjunction Elimination)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) from premise $P_1$ we get :

1) $(a ∨ b)$

2) $(c ∨ d)$.

In the same way, from $P_2$ we get :

3) $¬b$

4) $¬c$.

Then, using [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) we get :

5) $a$ --- from 1) and 3)

6) $d$ --- from 2) and 4)

7) $(a ∨ ¬d)$ --- from 5) by [Addition (or Disjunction Introduction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)

8) $(d ∨ ¬a)$ --- from 6)

> 9) $(a ∨ ¬d) \land (d ∨ ¬a)$ --- from 7) and 8) by [Adjunction (or Conjunction Introduction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction).

Comment: I can use all the inference rules and I think I have already got the given hints.

Comment: Like I also got your (5) and (6)

Comment: @KaiweiLuo - okay. From 5) $(a \lor \lnot d)$ and from 6) $(d \lor \lnot a)$. Then use Conjunction intro and it is done.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out! Thanks!